# Is there a way get lookup fields in random lists associated with a specific list programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-object-model

I have a sharepoint list, for example it is named as SourceList. I also have several lists which are associated to SourceList via lookup fields. I don't know the names or number of these lists\ they are created and being created dynamically. And any time a new list associated to SourceList can be created.

So, how can i get the lists associated to SourceList programmatically by Sharepoint object model? I know that i can iterate through lists and also the fields of the lists to check if it is a lookup field and associated to my SourceList. I don't want to do this for performance concerns but it will be my last chance if i can't find a better solution. And also i know i can query sharepoint db directly to get these lists but i will never want to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to access the list then the lookup field which should be of type  `SPFieldLookup` when you have this object the source list will be the `LookupList` property on that field.

They have a good example in this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldlookup.aspx